# Firefox - The URL is Not Valid and Cannot be Loaded, what url is it?

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox 3.6.15 (Ubuntu), and am having an issue with a website, `incontact.com`. When calls come in, a new, blank tab opens, and pops up an error: "The URL is Not Valid and Cannot be Loaded". This is from their tie-in software.

However, it would be *extremely* useful to me to find out what URL was not valid. Is there any way to actually log that information, or force Firefox to give it up?

Comment: It might not be the website's fault; try disabling your add-ons first.

Comment: It is the website's fault. Uses HTTPS and it throws up similar errors with chrome and IE.

Comment: Does their software run in-browser, or as a standalone program? If it's in-browser, does it use a plugin like Flash or Silverlight, or is it just plain HTML?

Comment: In browser, issue happens in Windows and Linux, likely due to trying to launch their windows-only extension software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension to Firefox, a very powerful web development tool.

The Firebug Console Panel lists all issued URLs, among all encountered JavaScript errors.

Just to remark, I tried Firebug on incontact.com and this website is absolutely FULL of JavaScript errors, which makes it a bit hard to see what is going on. I am not very impressed, and in your place I would have looked for an alternative.

Comment: Sadly, its not my choice to use that website, but I will do what I must to get it to not suck. :/

Comment: After fiddling about with firebug for about 30 minutes, I found that they're bouncing the opening command through a signed .jar. One step closer to figuring out what is actually going on here.

Comment: This might possibly help : [How to decompile a whole Jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file). And just to remark that accepting the answer and awarding the bounty are two distinct actions.

Comment: Figured out the decompilation and, essentially, its a jar that takes a variable and exec()s it. Did give you your well earned bounty, however. Still working on getting everything aligned right to catch the passed variable, but it looks possible now.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1. Check the Error Console (under Tools) to see if it gives you any additional specifics.
2. Try using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what URLs are being sent/received.

Comment: I'll give #1 a try. Sadly, I forgot to mention the site uses https, making analysis with wireshark pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with incontact.com, but in general you should be able to use a web traffic inspector to view the URL that is attempting to load.

An example would be the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) Firefox extention.

Comment: I doubt that, as I guess Firefox will not get that far. But maybe the question asker can give it a try...

Comment: I tried tamperdata for that... didn't give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the debug log:

```
export NSPR_LOG_MODULES="all:5" NSPR_LOG_FILE="/tmp/moz.log"
firefox &
```

Comment: Tried this one, managed to find the javascript files it requested from the server just before the window popped, but it didn't help me discover what data it was passing around.

Answer (score 0):

You were mentioning SSL, on Windows I know that you can use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as a [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) to sniff SSL traffic, this is done by allowing the program to add a certificate root to your OS which validates the SSL communication.

I see you've mentioned IE? Or is that just through WINE or a VM?

For Linux, there is [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) although that it's commercial (maybe trial suffices), [check these alternatives too](http://alternativeto.net/software/fiddler/).

Answer (score -1):

try running firefox in safe mode from the run command type firefox.exe -safe-mode You may also want to run Search and Destroy malware removal to see if there are any malware or bots hiding anywhere. In addition I would also recommend a registry checker which there are several on http://www.cnet.com/downloads Thank You for reading myn post!

Frank E Duffey
Franks Computers
Gainesville,FL

Comment: Your information is irrelevant, as I am not running Windows, I am running Ubuntu, as stated in my post.